# Proof by contradiction using counterexample

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples

Why can't we use one counterexample as the contradiction to the contradicting statement?

Example:
Let a statement be A where a-->b.
We can prove A is not true by finding a counter example.

Now, in another space and time, Let a new statement be B where it is the same as a-->not b.

Why can't we prove B is not true by finding a counter example?
Thus, a contradiction and A is true?

Comment: The negation of A is not B, so this reasoning won't work. The negation of A is instead a and not b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having both $A$, $B$, $a$ and $b$, let's make some of them $p$ and $q$.

Also, since you're talking about counterexamples, there must be a quantifier somewhere, so I guess you actually mean something like

$$ A \equiv \forall x\,(p(x)\to q(x)) $$
$$ B \equiv \forall x\,(p(x)\to \neg q(x)) $$

Having a counterexample to $A$ means that we have a particular $x_0$ such that $p(x_0)$ is true but $q(x_0)$ is false.

Similarly, having a counterexample to $B$ means that we have an $x_1$ such that $p(x_1)$ is true and $q(x_1)$ is also true.

There's no contradiction in having both counterexamples at the same time, because $x_0$ and $x_1$ will in general be *different* things -- as evidenced by the fact that $q$ is false for one of them and true for the other.

And also,just knowing these two counterexamples doesn't tell us anything about whether $p(x)$ is true for any *other* $x$, different from $x_0$ and $x_1$. There may be lots of other $x$s that $p$ is *false* for. Or there might not -- the example doesn't tell us anything either way.

Comment: Okay, so one counterexample to the contradicting statement is not sufficient to prove the original statement is true. What if  its possible to list all examples of the contradicting statement and show they don't hold, then the original statement must be true?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus: Which statements is it you claim are contradicting?

Comment: For any statement.  Say it is possible to show all examples do not hold for statement B, then A must be true?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus: You don't seem to be answering my question. Which two statements do you claim contradict each other?

Comment: The examples that do not hold for statement B is contradicting statement B.

Comment: @A_for_Abacus: And so what? That's just a counterexample to $B$ -- it doesn't have anything to do with $A$.

Comment: Not one example, if I can prove ALL possible examples that occur in A do not hold for statement B, then A must be true since B is the contradicting statement of A? Meaning if I can show ALL counterexamples to B.

Comment: @A_for_Abacus: If _every_ $x$ is such that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are both true, then of course there can be no counterexample to $A$, because a counterexample to $A$ must make $q$ _false_. But this hypothesis "_every_ $x$ is such that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are both true" does then not have much to do with $B$, since $B$ asserts that there isn't _any_ $x$ with this property.

Comment: Okay, so we can use counterexamples to disprove a contradiction, we just have to show all of them.

Comment: @A_for_Abacus: If you want to disprove a _contradiction_, you don't need any counterexamples. Contradictions are false _automatically_.

Comment: @A_for_Abacus: You're not thinking that $A$ and $B$ contradict each other, are you? They don't. It's perfectly possible for both of them to be true, if only $p(x)$ is false for all $x$.

Comment: @A_for_Abacus If statement $A$ is a **negation** of statement $B$, then proving $A$ is true means you have also proved $B$ is false.  If you want to *disprove* $A$ by showing a single counterexample to $A$, that is perfectly fine, and that would also prove $B$ is true.  The problem with your original question is that you assumed the statements $a \implies b$ and $a \implies \sim b$ are negations of each other.  This is simply not true.  Because they are not negations of each other, disproving one does not automatically prove the other.

Comment: Let's say A implies: if you have an apple, then it's red. Contradicting statement B states if you have an apple, then it's not red. If I take all apples in the world and show you that they are all red (all possible counterexamples to B) then statement A is true?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus When you say "contradicting statement" -- that is what I would call a *negation* or *negating statement*.  If $B$ is, as you call it, a contradicting statement of $A$, and $A$ is false, then yes, of course, this would imply $B$ is true.  Here is the problem with what you have been saying:  You just said the contradicting statement of "if you have an apple, then it's red" is "if you have an apple, then it is not red."  This is **incorrect**.  The contradicting statement of an "if, then" statement is **not** an "if, then" statement.

Comment: @A_for_Abacus The contradicting statement of "If $p$ then $q$" is the statement "$p$ and not $q$".  So, applied to your apple example, the contradicting statement to "if I have an apple, then it is red" is "I have an apple, and it is not red".

Comment: @A_for_Abacus I also want to say one more thing.  To find a counterexample for the statement "If I have an apple, then it is red," all you have to do is find **one** apple that is not red.  You do not have to check *every single apple*.  To contradict a statement about all apples, you just have to find *one apple* that does not meet the criteria of the statement.

Answer (score 4):

You can disprove the statement $a \implies \sim b$ using a counterexample if you can find one.  However, this does not prove the statement $a \implies b$.  This is because the negation of $a \implies \sim b$ isn't $a \implies b$.

Recall that the negation of an implication is **not** an implication.  $\sim (a \implies b) \equiv a \wedge \sim b$.  In words, this says that **the negation of "a implies b" is equivalent to "a and not b"**.

You are right that if a statement $B$ is the negation of a statement $A$, then $A$ being false implies $B$ is true, and $B$ being false implies $A$ is true.  The problem is, the negation of an implication is not an implication.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that:
$(a\implies b) \equiv (\neg a \lor b)$

Hence: $\therefore \neg (a\implies b) \equiv (a \land \neg b)$

The counter example of the implication is an event where $a$ happens *and* not $b$.

${\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline a & b & a\to b & a \land \neg b \\ \hline\hline F & F & T & F \\\hline F & T & T & F \\ \hline T & F & F & \color{red}{T} \\\hline T & T & T & F \\ \hline  \end{array}}$